# SQL query max value of a summarize

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently learning SQL and I am required to execute some SQL queries. There is one particular query that I fail to implement.

> Which are the clients who have (totally) the most expensive orders?

`customerid` and `total value` of all orders of the same customer must be returned as result.

The table is:

`Salesorderheader`:

```
salesorderid (int)   customerid (int)   totaldue (double)  
       1                 32000            3.20000
```

The database system I use is Postgresql. The query I got so far is:

```
SELECT totaldue, customerid 
FROM salesorderheader   
WHERE totaldue = (SELECT max(totaldue) FROM salesorderheader);
```

This query is wrong because a new value labeled as `total_value` (total value of all orders of the same customer) or something similar must be returned instead.

I know there that the SQL function `sum()` must be used combined with `GROUP BY customerid)`, but so far I failed to implement the correct query.

Thank you for your time.

**NOTE:** if I broke any site rules or this post is duplicate let me now and I'll delete this post immediately

[image: Sample for table]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gives biggest expences by clients:

```
SELECT distinct max(totaldue) over (partition by customerid),customerid 
FROM salesorderheader
order by 1 desc 
;
```

this shows the most wasting  client between all:

```
select sum(totaldue) over (partition by customerid),customerid 
    FROM salesorderheader
    order by 1 desc 
limit 1
    ;
```

Comment: Thank for your reply but your query is wrong. I need the maximum of total value of all orders of the same customer. for example if someone has 1 order with 120 as a value is lesser than someone who has 5 orders of 50 value

Comment: I dont see your table, but this should do the trick - mind the output is not limited

Comment: Still the result is wrong. i i uploaded a screenshot from my table (avoid the irrelevant columns). i think the use of `sum()` is required to implement the query

Comment: "the maximum of total value of all orders of the same customer." the sum of all orders for one customer is one value - there is no SUM. it is one value. if you want the max(value) per clients - then use my query... try rephrasing again - better make wanted output from your existig data

Comment: Sorry my bad English betrayed me.the max value per client is what i want i want to summarize all `totaldue` values with the same `customerid` and find the `max` one. i hope i made my self clear now.

Comment: then changing back the query - show the results and expected results in sample

Comment: as you can see:  customerid 29641 sum == 562463.475 
customerid 29614 sum == 2046152.0268. so  id 29614 total is more than id 29641 total. i want the bigger total as a returned value

Comment: I updated the answer. If I still don't understand, please using example explain what you want: client1  payed 1$ and 2$, clinet2 payed 4$, client3 payed 1$ and 6$. what result do you expect for these three clients?..

Comment: i think your query produces the correct output. thanks for you patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

select top 1 customer_id, sum(total_due) as total

into #top

from salesorderheader

group by customer_id

order by sum(total_due) desc;

select * from #top t

inner join salesorderheader soh

on soh.customer_id = t.customerid;

drop table #top;

I apologize for the formatting, I'm on mobile

Comment: Eric i cannot figure out what is the form of your actual query. Once i do i ll check if it works

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not realize this was a question about Postgres. The syntax is different but the idea is the same. Group by customer id and select the customer id and the sum of amount, and limit the results to one row order by sum of amount descending (this will give you the ID and sum of amount for the customer with the largest sum. Put these two values into a temp table and then join it back to the sales order header table on customer id. Then after that, drop the temp table so that you can run the query again if needed.

Comment: Reading your other comments it seems you are looking for the customer with the largest single order? In that case, just add another level of grouping (on whatever uniquely identifies the order) for the query that populates the temp table. That will give you the customer id with the largest single order.

Comment: mope no single order. the largest summarize of all customer orders

Comment: So if you group by customer_id and then sum amount, sort by sum of amount desc, that will list your customer IDs by total amount descending. Limit to one row and thats your top customer. Join that query back to the soh table to get detail of all sales orders